# Parse columns into separate arrays

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, awk, map-files

I have a space-delimited file:

```
Pool    Library Name    Email   Subject
Finland lib1    Guru    guru@abc.com,Narendra@abc.com   Finland Media Rotation
Tucson  lib2    Albert  abc@def.com Tucson Media Rotation
Vancouver   lib3    Jeff    ghi@abc.com Vancouver Media Rotation
```

I want to parse the columns into arrays like:

```
declare -a Pool=(Finland Tucson Vancouver)
declare -a Library=(lib1 lib2 lib3)
declare -a Name=(Guru Albert Jeff)
declare -a Email=("guru@abc.com,Narendra@abc.com" abc@def.com ghi@abc.com)
```

My code is:

```
column=1
for arrayname in Pool Library; do
     mapfile -t "$arrayname" < <(awk "NR > 1 {print \$$column}" file.txt)
     ((column++))
done
```

But it's failing in case of multiple items like in `Email`.

Comment: @GURUSINGH, Will `Name` field have spaces in between them or any other field?

Comment: If there are multiple names in EMAIL then it will be a comma in between them.

Comment: @GURUSINGH, No, I meant for `Name` column. I got the email part, how about Name column?

Comment: your project will be much easier to manage if you can use either tab-char or `|` as the field separator for your data. Good luck.

Comment: What is the problem with multiple email, given that they are separated with comma ?

Comment: Is this related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59098794/array-values-from-text-or-csv-file-in-shell ?

Comment: yes @dash-o its the same.

Comment: I am trying to get the solution for it from long but not able to get it

Comment: You are likely to get better feedback if you will clarify what is failing. 'Failing in case of multiple items` is not clear. Splitting the problem over multiple posts unlikely to get any complete answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58998007/picking-up-and-matching-multiple-values-from-array-shell-scripting,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59021512/how-to-remove-space-from-word-while-passing-it-in-array-in-shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v s1="\"" '
FNR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    header[i]=$i
  }
  val=length(header)
  next
}
{
  match($0,/.*\.com +/)
  string=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  num=split(string,array," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    values[i]=(values[i]?values[i] OFS:"")s1 array[i] s1
  }
  values[num+1]=(values[num+1]?values[num+1] OFS:"")substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  delete array
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=val;i++){
    print "declare -a " header[i] "=(" values[i]")"
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

This will print the array creation commands on terminal, you could use the as per your need.

Comment: thanks for your help. your code works like charm.I need one little help too, that now how to pass these arguments to my script.

Comment: @GURUSINGH, Np. Please have 1 question and 1 thread only, you could open a new thread with your EFFORTS which you have put in order to solve your own problem, cheers and happy learning.